# phpQuery: How to parse the tr's class and style clause

Tags: phpquery

I have a script parsing a html page.  One section parses the various tr elements.  Suppose we have a tr structure like this:

```
<tr class="a test" style="display: none;">
  <td class="numeric"></td>
  <td class="date">1/1/16</td>
  <td class="numeric">$2.65</td>
  .... etc....
</tr>
<tr class="another tr">
  ...... etc......
```

The current code which is working fine is something like this:

```
$the_row_I_want = $parseSectionofCodeImlookingat->find("tr:eq($rowIwant)");
$entire_tr_in_html = $the_row_I_want->__toString();
```

What this does is return the html for the entire tr, from which I can parse out the class name and style sections.  However I have been trying to find out how to use phpQuery syntax to parse the class name and style section out for me.  Is there a way to do this using phpQuery (and how)?

Answer (score 0):

OK, figured it out:

```
$the_row_I_want = $parseSectionofCodeImlookingat->find("tr:eq($rowIwant)");
$entire_tr_in_html = $the_row_I_want->__toString();
$the_class_attribute = $the_row_I_want->attr('class');
$the_style_attribute = $the_row_I_want->attr('style');
```